# My JButtons are bugged

Tags: java, swing

I am having problems with drawing a 2D `JButton` array to a `JFrame`. All the `JButtons` draw properly except for the last one, the last `JButton` to be rendered is fitted to the `JFrame`. I have set the width and height of all the `JButtons` to `100x100`, but the last `JButton` to render does not have a width and height of `100x100`. I printed the properties of the console, and it said the button height and width was `494X496`.

Main class that runs everything:

```
package gameData;

import javax.swing.*;

public class GameRun {

    JFrame frame;
    ActionHandle AH = new ActionHandle();
    Screen screen = new Screen();

    public GameRun() {
        beginSession();
        screen.renderScreen(frame, AH);
    }

    public void beginSession() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(500, 525);;
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("Game");
        this.frame = frame;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GameRun();
    }

}
```

how the `JButtons` are drawn:

```
package gameData;

import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Screen {
    public void renderScreen(JFrame frame, ActionListener AL){
        JButton[][] button = new JButton[5][5];
        for(int i =0; i<button.length;i++){
            for(int j = 0; j<button[i].length; j++){
                button[i][j] = new JButton(i+" "+j);
                button[i][j].setBounds(i*100, j*100, 100, 100);
                button[i][j].addActionListener(AL);
                frame.add(button[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `JFrame` uses a `BorderLayout` by default, so you are adding all the buttons to the same location on the frame, possibly overlapping them.  Instead, you should consider using a `GridBagLayout` instead. See [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more details
2. You should override the buttons `getPreferredSize` method if you want to affect they way in which the buttons are laid out.
3. You should really call `setResizable` before you set the size of the frame
4. You should use `pack` instead of `setSize`, frames have window decorations which get fitted inside the window, not added to it, this will affect the amount of viewable space you have for the content, `pack` will do all these calculations for you
5. You should be creating/modifying your UI from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, see [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details

For example...

[image: Buttons]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            JButton[][] button = new JButton[5][5];
            for (int i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
                gbc.gridx = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < button[i].length; j++) {
                    button[i][j] = new JButton(i + " " + j) {
                        @Override
                        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                            return new Dimension(100, 100);
                        }
                    };
                    add(button[i][j], gbc);
                    gbc.gridx++;
                }
                gbc.gridy++;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Beware when playing with `getPreferredSize`, fonts are generally not rendered the same on all platforms and this will affect what you program looks look on different platforms. In you case, chaning the `margins` of the button might be safer

Comment: for learning purpose, why should `setResizable` be called before setting the size if we set it to false anyway ?

Comment: `setResizable` changes the frames border decorations, changing the amount of available space that is available to the content area, but it doesn't always get update properly.

Comment: So if for example I call `setUndecorated(true)` right before, then it would not matter anymore ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard Possibly not, because the content area is controlled by the `JRootPane`.  Even invalidating the frame doesn't update the `contentPane` propertly for some reason.  The best solution, call `setResizable` first, the change the size, better yet, simply call `pack` and allow the layout manager API to deal with it

Comment: Well, I may not have used your solution, I have solved my problem. It looks like I was forgetting to use a layout manager.